# Timestamp format from dateTimePicker with hours

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert datetime from a datetimepicker to unix timestamp but with options to select a specified hour and minutes from a textbox and then to be show in other textbox. Here is my code so far for make a timestamp fot a date:

```
public static long ToUnixTimestamp(DateTime target)
    {
        var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, target.Kind);
        var unixTimestamp = System.Convert.ToInt64((target - date).TotalSeconds);

        return unixTimestamp;
    }

    public static DateTime ToDateTime(DateTime target, long timestamp)
    {
        var dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, target.Kind);

        return dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
        textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}", ToUnixTimestamp(dt));

    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: Basicly I want to change the hours and minutes manualy from a textbox.